# Add user control to tab page

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

How to add user control to tab page from Designer. Is it possible or it can be done only from code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any usercontrols that you have created usually shows up in the "[Your Project Name] Component" tab in the toolbox. 
you might need to rebuild the project to make sure it refreshes fine

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be done in the designer.

Your user control can be registered in the `Toolbox` and subsequently selected and dropped onto a form.

The user control need not be kept in a separate project. If it is not visible in the `Toolbox`, you can add them manually by 'Choose Items...' option (in VS2010 - think it is 'Customize...' in 2008)

Answer (score 2):

Keep the UserControl in a separate project. Drag and drop it from the "My User Controls" section of the toolbox.

Read the **Testing Your Contol** section in the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207(v=vs.71).aspx